# How to change input value as per custom numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to change range value as per given custom value in screen shot. Right now I'm getting 1,2,3,4,5,6 values onchange of range but I need 6,12,24,36,48,60 values. How can I do this?

[image]

**My Code:**

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range"min="1" max="6" steps="1" value="1" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

ThankYou for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snippet solves your problem

Changing this.value to set values in an array

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range"min="1" max="6" steps="1" value="1" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
values = [6,12,24,36,48,60];
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = values[this.value-1];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a array and store the values you need in your slider.

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range"min="0" max="5" steps="1" value="0" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var values = ["6 mo","12 mo","24 mo","36 mo","48 mo","60 mo"];
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

slider.oninput = function(){
    output.innerHTML = values[this.value];
};
slider.oninput();

</script>
```

Comment: Actually, there's even no need for arrays for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed range you can use this method.

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range"min="1" max="6" steps="1" value="1" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");


var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value === "1" ? '6 mo' : slider.value;

function myFunction(pos) {
  const myMonths = [6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]
  return myMonths[pos - 1] + ' mo'
}


slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = myFunction(this.value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `min`, `max`, and `step` attributes to control the range of slider, without any need of JavaScript.

Also, There's a typo in your code. The name of attribute is `step` not `steps`.

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="6" max="60" step="6" value="6" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

If you want "mo" after the value, you can just do `output.innerHTML = this.value + "mo";`